# Event registration during and after an AJAX call (for a remote store to load)

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, event-handling, dom-events

1. Assuming 'load' is fired after 1 ms and the first listener registered by the computer after 2 ms. Will someFunctionB be called?
2. Assuming 'load' is fired after 800 ms and the first listener registered by the computer after 2 ms, and the second listener after 3 ms. Will someFunctionB be called for both indices?

Code:

```
SomeClass = Ext.Extend(SomeSuperClass,
   initComponent: function () {
      this['someStore'] = new Ext.data.Store({
         proxy: x('y/z.asmx/s'),
         reader:JSONReader([
            { name: 'g', type: 'string', mapping: 'g' },
         ]),
         sortInfo: { field: 'g', direction: "ASC" }
         });
         this['someStore'].load(
         {
            params:
            {
              ID: this.config.id
            }
        });
        for(var i = 0;i<2;i++){
           this.someFunctionA(i);
        }
    }
    someFunctionA: function(index){
       this['someStore'].on("load", function() {this.someFunctionB(index);}, this);
    }
    someFunctionB: function(index){
       var record = this['someStore'].getAt(index);
       console.log(record);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you give it a try yourself and see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No 2. Yes.....................